# mvc 5 attributes on controller are being ignored

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, controller, custom-attributes, actionfilterattribute

A few months ago I wrote a WebApi app with a some custom attributes. It works great.

I am now writing a new MVC 5.2.3 website and wanted to include the same attributes. I moved them over and the project builds and runs just fine except that the attributes are being ignored.

This is my controller decoration:

```
[AuthorizeIt(Roles = "theRole")] 
[LogRequestResponse] 
public class HomeController : Controller{}
```

This the signature of my two attributes:

```
public class LogRequestResponseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthorizeItAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
```

I can include more code but I don't think it is actually a code problem since it works in my other website. My guess it is a difference between the MVC and WebApi and there is some little detail I am missing.

And yes, i am aware that ASP.core integrates webApi and MVC and would solve the problems I am facing however my job will have not allow this.

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: Additional info: New Info: If I change my controller to inherit from ApiController my attributes work fine. Change backand they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I solved most of my problems and have one last item that I cannot solve.
In a nutshell  at the highest level in regard to attributes the WebAPI and MVC appear to have objects that are the same but as you go deeper things really get different.

For example: AuthorizeAttribute is very different depending on the namespace you use. The MVC version wants a AuthorizationContext parameter while WebApi wants a HttpActionContext.

Another example is that OnActionExecuted function wants a ActionExecutedContext as parameter for MVC but webApi wants a HttpActionExecutedContext.

The bottom line is all I could do was take my original WebApi attributes put them in my MVC project and then starting at the top make sure you are in the MVC namespace and then start drilling down and changing the objects as needed.

I was able to find an MVC equivalent for every webApi peice of code except one.

For WebAPI, in the OnActionExecuted function I can get to the the content of the response with:

```
    var response = actionContext.Response?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

where:

```
actionContext is a HttpActionExecutedContext
```

But in MVC

```
actionContext is a ActionExecutedContext
```

So the webapi code above that is getting the response won't work in MVC.
From what I have been reading the response content in MVC is located at:

```
actionContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter
```

which is a stream. But no matter how many different ways I have tried to read the stream it is always in an unreadable state.

**The last unanswered part of my question is:**

MVC 5: I am writing an custom attribute. I am in the function:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionContext)
```

And I want to read the the Response content so I can for example log it or alter it, or whatever.

**In summary:**

1. The general solution to the question is to carefully start at the top of the custom attributes, change the name space to MVC and then work through the code replacing the WEBapi code with the MVC equivalent. Very annoying and tedious. If anyone is trying something similar and has questions I'd be happy to help.
2. There is one last piece of the code that I cannot find a translation for  and hope someone else knows the answer.

Thanks....Bob